# Get values from a select when option value changes

Tags: angular

I need to get the selected item in a select property. This is how I get it

```
<div class="form-group">
<label>Plaza</label>
    <select 
      formControlName="plaza" 
      class="browser-default custom-select mb-4"
      (change)="onPlazaChange($event)"
    >
        <option value="" disabled>Plaza</option>
        <option 
          *ngFor="let plaza of plazas" 
          [ngValue]="plaza"
        >{{plaza.name}}</option>
     </select>
</div>

onPlazaChange(event: any) {
    console.log(event.target.value);
}

export class Plaza {
    id?: string;
    name: string;
    code: number;
    lanes: Lane[];
}

export class Lane {
    number: number;
    type: string;
}
```

I don't know what's wrong but I should get the object plaza not just the id alone. All I get is "Object".

Comment: I thik this link will help you...http://plnkr.co/edit/VbJUBkqAlS8UPVgh4bqV?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`select` dropdown is to get the checked value not recommended to get complete the Object.

So get the **`Id`** of the object and compare it in the TS file to filter it.

**Template :**

```
<select  formControlName="plaza" 
      class="browser-default custom-select mb-4"
      (change)="onPlazaChange($event)"
    >
        <option value="" disabled>Plaza</option>
        <option 
          *ngFor="let plaza of plazas" 
          [value]="plaza.id"
        >{{plaza.name}}</option>
     </select>
```

**Ts:**

```
onPlazaChange(event: any) {
    console.log(event.target.value);
    const id = event.target.value;
    const selectedPlaza = this.plazas.filter(plaza => plaza.id == id);
}
```

> P.S : don't use **`ngModelChange`** and **`change`** in select tag(only `change` is enough)

hope this helps.. ;)

Comment: Your suggestion is very appreciated Sir. The problem is, it gives me a result of "4: Z7vb5mMBhauz0tDq2YpD" the 4: is included that's why the filter doesn't work. How do I remove that "4: "?

Comment: I have seen that `id` is optional in your Plaza object so it is better to use other parameter which is a mandatory field(ex. `name`).

Comment: Thank you Sir. I just combined substring() and trim(). It's working now. Thank you so much Sir.

Comment: glad to help you.. :)

Answer (score 1):

[value]="plaza" is always a string to get object you have to use [ngValue]="plaza"

Here is a stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hy1xw9?file=app/app.component.html
where the 1st one is incorrect and second is correct

You can use ngModel to get the value, I am not sure why it is not showing the details with event.target.value.

```
  <h3>Using <code>ngValue</code></h3>

    <select [(ngModel)]="selectedNode" (change)="onNodeChange()"  >
      <option [ngValue]="null">All nodes</option>
      <option *ngFor="let node of nodes" [ngValue]="node">
        {{ node.id }} - {{ node.name }}
      </option>
    </select>
```

```
onNodeChange() {
    console.log( JSON.stringify(this.selectedNode));
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-oyn97w

Comment: I just get "Object". I need the whole object. Not just the id alone. On your stack you just output the "node.id"

Comment: I have edited my answer, this should work if you can use ngModel

Comment: I have read that using nte [ngModel] is depecrated and is removed is angular7. I am using angular 8....